# Multiple instances and multiple destinations

Tags: python, logging, configuration

I have multiple Python modules, each of which has separate log config files. I am using Yaml, so I just do a

```
    log_config_dict=yaml.load(open(config_file1, 'r'))
    logging.config.dictConfig(log_config_dict)             
    self.main_logger=logging.getLogger('Main_Logger')
```

In another module, I have something like

```
   log_config_dict=yaml.load(open(config_file2, 'r')) 
   logging.config.dictConfig(log_config_dict)       
   self.main_logger=logging.getLogger('Poller_Main_Logger')
```

The 2 loggers are writing to separate log files. Then in the code for each separate module, I do logging as -

```
     self.main_logger.info(log_str)
```

However this is not working as expected. Say I do logging from module1,then from module2, then from module1 again, the log messages are either written to module2's destination, or not written at all.

Any idea what is happening? Is the problem that each time I do a dictConfig call, previous loggers are disabled? Is there any way around this?

Below - one of the log config files

```
version: 1
formatters:
  default_formatter:
    format: '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s'
    datefmt: '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
  plain_formatter:
    format: '%(message)s'
handlers:  
  console_default_handler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: default_formatter
    stream: ext://sys.stdout  
  console_error_handler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: default_formatter
    stream: ext://sys.stderr  
  logfile_handler:    
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: logger.txt
    mode: a
    formatter: default_formatter
    level: DEBUG    
  errfile_handler:    
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: error.txt
    mode: a
    formatter: default_formatter
    level: WARNING    
  plain_handler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: plain_formatter
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
  Poller_Main_Logger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console_default_handler,logfile_handler]
    propagate: no
  Plain_Logger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [plain_handler]
    propagate: no
  Error_Logger:
    level: WARNING
    handlers: [errfile_handler,console_error_handler,logfile_handler]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [console_default_handler]
```

Comment: What's in your yamls?  My bet is that the dicts being loaded in are all defaulting to modifying the root logger because they don't specify otherwise.

Comment: Here is one of them: See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logging` doesn't support the usage pattern you want here.  By default, rerunning `logging.config.dictConfig()` blows away all existing loggers, handlers, and formatters.  There are the `incremental` and `disable_existing_loggers` options available for use in the config dict, but using `incremental`, you can't load in new handlers or formatters.  You either need to combine you configuration in to a single file for your whole program, or use the mechanisms provided in the module to manually construct and add formatters and handlers to loggers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't find much information on incremental. If you have any links, would you post them please? Thanks

Comment: I mostly just looked at the code in the logging module, but http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#incremental-configuration

Comment: Oh, you looked at the code itself. Because that paragraph doesn't say much...I mean it's more like an abstract comment

Comment: The important piece is you can't do what you want the way you want to do it, really.  The logger configurators are built around the idea that you run them once before you ever use the loggers to log anything.  If you want to modify how they behave after you've already configured them (implicitly by logging anything or explicitly), you need to do that via the manual mechanisms for managing loggers.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, I will write some code to manually do it. But it's a shame that we don't have this feature